# RabbitMQ using Spring boot, should create Queue if it does not exist

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I am sending data to RabbitMQ from multiple sources, if the queue does not exist, i want to create it.

```
public void sendMessage(String message, String routingKey) {
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(routingKey, message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#broker-configuration.

With Spring Boot, you just need to add a `Queue` `@Bean` because Boot will automatically configure a `RabbitAdmin` bean, which will find it and provision it when the connection is first opened.

You can also add exchanges and bindings.

```java
@Bean
public Queue queue() {
    return QueueBuilder.nonDurable("foo")
        .autoDelete()
        .exclusive()
        .withArgument("foo", "bar")
        .build();
}
```

If the queue exists already, it must have the same properties and arguments.

Comment: thanks for replying, what if the queue name is dynamic? it will depend on some other factor like the name of the table in our rdbms etc. how to create a queue in this case?

Comment: See the link to the docs. The admin has methods that allow you to programmatically create queues etc.